# Why do MATLAB questions on Stack Overflow not tend to appear in the top of Google search results?

Tags: discussion, google

So, I recently started learning [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) for a course I'm taking and had the odd experience of having other Q&A sites (including MATLAB's discussion forum) routinely outrank Stack Overflow results (if there even was a Stack Overflow result at all). Irritatingly enough, these tend to be plagued by the usual problems that plague discussion forums: having to wade through all kinds of thread hijacking, sort-of answers, and "me too!" type comments to get the information I need.

I got to thinking: why is this? Is there a low user base for this tag on Stack Overflow? Do all of them just go to the MATLAB forums instead?

I'm also interested in whether or not there's something that we could do about this as a community (at least partially for the selfish reason that I find it much easier to find information in Stack Overflow's Q&A format than I do in most discussion forums). For example, as I search for stuff, would it be helpful to future readers to document stuff I find with self-answered questions (assuming that it doesn't already exist elsewhere on Stack Overflow)? (Personally, even if the information already exists elsewhere, I would still prefer to have it here in a "clean" Q&A format so that the information is easy to find).

Comment: Matlab is somehow a niche in programming questions here (that's what I've been experiencing in conjunction of questions appearing in the c++ tag). Questions mostly come from people, which don't do programming as their primary goal, but do analysis with matlab in front. I came to know matlab and simulink myself mostly from my work experience at communications industry, as a tool to simulate (and visualize) HW behavior.

Comment: FWIW, [Matlab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) is also on-topic on [maths.se].

Comment: You can't shift a community's focus unilaterally by wanting it different! MATLAB evidently long predates Stack Overflow and its support forums and methods do so too. As already mentioned, it has a large user base of engineers and scientists, many of whom may use almost nothing else (apart from  mailer, browser, word/text processor, etc.) and don't identify as programmers.

Comment: I've noticed the same pattern with Stata which is similar in this sense (1) a proprietary platform maintained by a dedicated company (2) a user community that is highly open in sharing the extra code written and supporting each other. Statalist was started in 1994 as a list server, changed to a web forum in 2014, and still gets far more Stata questions than all other sites combined. I've seen the occasional suggestion that people should "just move" to Stack Overflow, but it never happened.

Comment: @NickCox I don’t see how MATLAB predating Stack Overflow is particularly relevant: the same is true for most technologies discussed on Stack Overflow (except in the JavaScript ecosystem, obviously …). Virtually all of these had extensive online resources before Stack Overflow came along, but nowadays the latter outranks almost all of them.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph There is no universal explanation. If explanations must mention only  factors unique to particular software and factors that apply to more than one software to different degrees can't be mentioned, then you will explain very little.  Indeed. as another example, R help predated Stack Overflow but has been eclipsed by Stack Overflow. Other details were important in that too, including people active on R help fading away. But the fact that a company is behind MATLAB is a powerful force to maintaining the status quo. Turn it around: what is your answer to the question?

Comment: @NickCox My answer is precisely that: MATLAB is a commercial product and the “competition” to Stack Overflow is part of the official, commercial support for the software.

Comment: OK, so you agree with my point (1). That's good but why not say so?

Comment: "I got to thinking: why is this?" – Google Search is highly personalized. That fact that you are commenting on the quality of those other forums implies that you are visiting them. Google will notice that you tend to visit links from those forums and rank them even higher for you. In regards to the official website, it was already mentioned in other comments and answers that it is probably ranked highly by Google because it is, well, the official website.

Comment: @NickCox: R is both a good and a bad example, because the R community *actively* moved to [main]. They both collaborated with the SO community, SO moderators, and Stack Overflow, Inc. as well as with each other to rewrite significant portions of their knowledge base in the form of question and answer pairs, and pre-seeded the [tag:r] tag with this knowledge base. They also made sure that high-level community members, developers, and moderators from the old community were active in the [tag:r] tag. They even did specific training in SO etiquette for their community leaders, IIRC.

Comment: So, it was well-planned, well-executed, conscious, and deliberate move to SO, just like there seems to be an equally deliberate effort on the part of MathWorks, Inc. to *stay off* Stack Overflow. Which is of course their right. The MATLAB community *could* do this as well, but as mentioned, the company does not want to do that, and thus SO will never have access to the developers like the official forums do.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the input. You're better informed than I am on the details, but the story on R sounds weird to me: high-level users or developers of any software are free spirits in my experience and can't be made or instructed to do what they don't want to do any way,  unless they are employees. FWIW, I am not an active user of MATLAB but often bump against it. I'd say that the company behind MATLAB is more likely to be alive and well in say 5 years' time than Stack Overflow, so keeping their distance is prudent from their point of view.  Meanwhile, some good answers here now.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Nice story about _R_ planned migration to SO!

Comment: @NickCox: "high-level users or developers of any software are free spirits in my experience and can't be made or instructed to do what they don't want to do any way" – Correct. And those free spirits collectively decided that it was stupid to expend resources, time, effort, and money to duplicate what (in their opinion) Stack Overflow did better than them. Let the R community worry about R and Stack Overflow, Inc. worry about building a knowledge repository.

Comment: Has anyone ever tried to argue with Google that they might systematically rank content the wrong (less useful) way and won? Although the Matlab forum is also useful. They have answerers who know what they are doing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This is only tangentially related but I find it worth pointing out that this active R campaign is somewhat of a mixed blessing because the initial concerted upvoting essentially gamed the system. As a consequence, Stack Overflow has many very highly upvoted older R answers which are actually completely wrong.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Intriguing. Well, I was sternly advised to let the R community worry about R, and I will, but there are just about 400,000 questions... It seems that the very highest number of votes go to threads with many different answers too, so perhaps people can choose.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd say there is a user base for MATLAB on Stack Overflow, evidenced by [29 gold badge holders](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/169/matlab), myself among those, and a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave) where most of the active gold badge holders hang out.

MATLAB Answers being prevalent in the search results isn't too strange, given that The MathWorks, the makers of MATLAB, are also behind that. I've heard rumours they've been asked to either sponsor the [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag, or even a full MATLAB.SE, but have declined, pointing to their own forum. Thus, the MATLAB employees will be answering there, getting you information us mere mortal users of MATLAB would not be able to get.

The problem I see with the MATLAB tag is that it's mainly used by students. Meaning that [eternal september](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) is a very real thing in the tag. Most of the questions boil down to two categories: 1) homework dumps, 2) project dumps ("I was asked to do image analysis. Plz write, kk thx"). The people I'm acquainted with through the chatroom do sometimes answer those, but also routinely get tired of seeing the same questions over and over again. I'd say MATLAB Answers is less susceptible to that, given that the top contributors are paid by The MathWorks.

Answer (score 16):

> other Q&A sites (including MATLAB's discussion forum) routinely outrank Stack Overflow results

Is this true though? MATLAB Answers usually outranks Stack Overflow, but it’s on the product manufacturer’s site, so it is logical that Google would rank it highest. I don’t know of any other Q&A sites that show up in Google searches.

I do see blog posts and tutorials come up, but not other Q&A sites.

> if there even was a Stack Overflow result at all

I think we have a very large collection of good Q&A on MATLAB here. Even many esoteric questions have been answered. Some of those are hard to find though, because of the large collection of poor questions (homework dumps as suggested [by Adriaan in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406729/7328782)) that sit in the way. We don’t have enough curation in the tag to close all of them in time, too many are answered.

I do get disappointed by the duplication of effort between SO and MATLAB Answers. I am active here and not there exactly for the same reasons you want to find answers here and not there: insufficient moderation here is still orders of magnitude better than non-existent moderation there.

When googling, add “site:stackoverflow.com” to your search.

Comment: _When googling, add “site:stackoverflow.com” to your search._ … well said!

Comment: I actually find not adding "site:" works better. Just "stackoverflow.com" as the first term. Might be worth a try.